# Calling setInterval and clearInterval functions inside multiple javascript objects

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to use "setInterval" and "clearInterval" functions inside js objects created with "new" operator.

html:

```
<button onclick="testList.push(new Test());">run</button>
```

js:

```
Test = function(){
   this.y = 0;
   this.dy = 10;
   that = this;
   this.interval = setInterval(function(){
        that.y += that.dy;
        if (that.y>300){
            console.log(that.y);  //prints y in console
            clearInterval(that.interval);
        }
   }, 10);
}
```

[**JFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jur0fpcp/)

When I click the "run" button once this works as I expect. But when I click the "run" button multiple times before a previous interval is not cleared (when click the button multiple times quickly), then intervals are not cleared and y is incremented infinitely. What is the mistake I'm making here?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Wondering why you are using a function expression to create the constructor rather than a function declaration.

Comment: @Robg Any disadvantages of using a function expression here (other than the function is not defined until this line is executed)?

Comment: That's about it, there is a lot written here: [*var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname). I prefer to see declarations over expressions, where expressions are used for assignments only. But others prefer to use expressions everywhere so everything is an assignment. Horses for courses… ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a global variable `that` which overwites previous `Test` instance references:

```
that = this;
```

You should use `var` keyword when you declare variables:

```
var that = this;
```